# Manage DB connections with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

we are having problems with connection pooling our DB connections (Otherwise we encounter “Cannot obtain database connection”).

For some reason we need to define a connection per Sidekiq worker we have running which will limit us in the very near future in terms of scaling our pods above the number connections we have available to our database.

So, for example, if each of our sidekiq processes has max 100 workers and our max database connections is 3500, we can have max 35 sidekiq processes up.

Anyone have a similar environment and can share some insights on how to have sidekiq workers re-use the database connections?

Ideally, I think the number of connections should be approx. 10% of the number of running workers and then having the workers re-using the connections to the DB.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean "worker". But when you have 10 Sidekiq processes with concurrency 25 per each, you must dedicate 250 DB connections to them. Otherwise it will no sense to have such concurrency setup.

Comment: You don't have to define a connection per thread. (Please don't use the term Worker, it's nebulous)

Comment: You can set concurrency to 25 and your db pool to 15, for example.  Don't set concurency higher than 50.

Comment: Hey Mike, any special setup we need to make in the database.yml and sidekiq.yml for the concurrency of 25 and pool of 15 other than just stating those numbers?

Comment: What is the ideal setup in terms of concurrency per sidekiq process? 100 concurrent workers works fine for us in terms of performance, the only issue we currently have (or are aware of) is the issue of re-using DB connections.

Comment: https://twitter.com/nateberkopec/status/1038157458752122880